# URL ReWriter for .NET

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I am using [this](http://urlrewriter.net/), but I have some hard to solve problems.

This is part of my code:

```
 <rewrite url="/Dictionary/(.+)/(.+)" to="~/Dictionary.aspx?page=$2&amp;&amp;word=$1"/>
 <rewrite url="/Dictionary" to="~/Dictionary.aspx"/>
```

When I type links like mywebsite.com/Dictionary/cat/4 the site loads only mywebsite.com/Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess. Your second condition matches everything starting with /Dictionary.
You probably want this

```
/Dictionary/?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but you can also try out [IIS Url Rewrite 2 instead](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewrite 2 is a good option like XII said, comes with an user interface.

Regarding the regex, it would be more efficient for the regex engine to avoid backtracking; use the following expression instead:

"/Dictionary/([^/]+)/([^/]+)"